# I got messages from Viber maximum free messages from Bot exceeded

Tags: php, bots, viber-bot

I got this answer when sending 500 messages in batches by 300
(chatapi.viber.com/pa/broadcast_message - sending REST URL).
It was working until last week i start getting this as response:

```
(
    [status] => 23
    [status_message] => maximum free messages from Bot exceeded.
    [message_token] => 5748679331176400537
    [chat_hostname] => SN-CHAT-02_
)
```

Doea anybody know What is this maximum? Was unable find it in Viber doc!

Nothing is write about this in Viber API documentation for broadcast_message (https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#broadcast-message)!

Comment: https://respond.io/blog/viber-bot-pricing ...?

Answer (score -1):

i check t&d of viber, they expain with bot, can send 10k messages in month
Do you check and count message which sent in this month

To engage in a conversation with their subscribers, a chatbot owner can send chatbot-initiated messages. Chatbot owners will be charged a cost-per-message beyond 10,000 chatbot-initiated messages sent every calendar month.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).